# assign Date and time as output file name

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I use C# to start and stop 'ffmpeg' process, and I can easily name my output file like this:

```
"-f image2 -framerate 10 -i " + d + "\\%06d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -r 10
 -crf 37 -pix_fmt yuv420p E:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_h_mm_ss_tt") + ".flv";
```

but I wonder if I can do it using only `ffmpeg` to be some thing like this:

```
 "ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -c:v libx264 -r 10
     -crf 37 -pix_fmt yuv420p E:\D_M_Y_H_M_S_T.flv"
```

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us) is very close to what i need, one thing in deffrent i need all of it in cmd

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811758/assign-date-and-time-to-output-file/22813968#22813968 (described more precisely there)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, change the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` output format:

```
string filename = "-f image2 -framerate 10 -i " + d + "\%06d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -r 10 -crf 37 -pix_fmt yuv420p E:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_hh_mm_ss") + ".flv";
```

Note that I missed out days (`dd`) as you did in your example, but that might be a mistake by you.

Comment: oh i mean to do all of it without C#