# CMD: Save date and time as a file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote script to remove temporary files. 
Script creates log with all files removed:

`SET RemoveLog=RemoveLog_%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-10,2%_%date:~-7,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%.txt` (that will create file like `RemoveLog_2014_03_09__09_12.txt`)

and to save something in this log I use:

`ECHO. >> %MEMLET%\%RemoveLog%`  (Empty line in this case)

This have been working fine so far but on one laptop something else is happening.

File is saved as `RemoveLog_2014_03_09__` (`09_12.txt` is missing)

And everywhere I used `>> %MEMLET%\%RemoveLog%` in the script, In the log at the end of every line i see `9_12.txt`

Why is this happening?

Comment: The laptop has a different date format

Comment: How to save date in file so will work everywhere?

Comment: I have answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22813968/2152082

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/2861476) you have a nice list of options

Answer (score 1):

You don't get what you expected because `%DATE%` returns the current date using the windows settings for the "short date format". This setting is fully (endlessly) customizable.

One user may configure its system to show the short date as `Wed030914`; while another user (even in the same system) may choose `09/03/2014`. It's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

One possible solution is to use **WMIC**, instead. WMIC is the WMI command line interface to WMI. **WMI** *Windows Management Instrumentation* is the  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation

```
WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table
```

returns the date in a convenient way to directly parse it with a `FOR`.

Completing the parse and putting the pieces together

```
 FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') DO (
    SET REMOVELOG=RemoveLog_%%F_%%D_%%A_%%B_%%C.txt
 )
```

Comment: this will not have leading zeros for day, month, hour, minute, second.

Comment: it answers your question, avoiding the %date% format problem. You need to build your solution around it. You might also try `WMIC OS get localdateTime`